# Dependent current source with capacitor

Tags: voltage, capacitor, thevenin

In this electronics problem, I want to determine the expression of the capacitor voltage.

The switch closes at t=0. The initial capactior voltage is 10V.

I tried to do a Thevénin equivalent circuit, and for that I assumed that the switch was on. I had no problem finding the R equivalent. But when I tried to determine the Thévenin voltage due to the current source, I wasn't able to obtain it.

What I did:
\$\ 7I=I_1+I_2\$ (1) and\$\ R_1I_1=R_2I_2\$ (2)

But because \$\ I=I_2 \$, the equation yields\$\ I_1 =6I_2\$ and i get nothing when I substitute this result into the (2) equation.

If I could have the value of the V thévenin, I think I could solve this easily.

But if this problem isn't meant to be solved by the equivalent circuit, should I I consider the closed switch and the current \$\ 7I \$ to flow through the capacitor?Am i missing something?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Picture of the circuit]

Comment: You forgot to deal with the capacitor current. Can you figure out how to include it? Are you at all familiar with nodal analysis?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But can't I ignore the capacitor if i want to find the equivalent circuit?

Comment: I can't see how can I solve this problem without "cleaning up" the right side of the circuit.

Comment: I'd use nodal analysis and an integrating factor to solve it. I don't see how to convert this to a Thevenin equivalent, first. But I'm up in the middle of the night and will be going back to sleep, shortly. So it may be my state of mind, only. Using nodal, this seems almost trivial, though.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try that :)

Comment: Given that the dependent current source is injecting current **into** the top node at a rate that is 7 times the amount that \$R_2\$ sinks it, coupled with the fact that \$R_1\$ can only sink twice that much (for a total of \$3\,I\$), it follows that an additional \$4\,I\$ (if my brain is working okay right now) will be charging \$C\$. This means that the voltage result you get should increase with time, and exponentially so. Just keep that in mind when you work out a result.

Comment: Raquel, how are you proceeding on this. Everything okay? Or do you still have any questions?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I tried to do it like you said, I understood it. But because there are no solutions, I can't evaluate what I did. Thank you so much for you help.

Comment: Could you write, add, what you tried to the question? Or would you prefer I just show you how?

Comment: I found the solution today when I was practising for my exam in a book! haha, Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks. That confirms my intuition about it. But it adds a method for conversion I would not have used to get there. Cute.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution in a book called "Electric Circuits" by Nilsoon and Riedel

[image]

[image]